# Running a cluster of 65 Raspberry Pis with one SD Card (is it possible?)

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, server, cluster

I've recently gotten the task of setting up a Raspberry Pi cluster (64 Raspberry Pi, and 1 PXE server running on the 65th Raspberry Pi)

As this project is not 100% built by me, and the guy who built it has now left the company. I am wondering if it's possible to somehow connect all of these up with just a shingle SD Card, and a local hard drive with 10 TB of storage.

I could successfully set up the first Raspberry Pi with the SD Card and now running an installation of Raspberry OS.

So my question really is, if it's possible to set up the rest of Raspberry Pis with an instance of OS running on the hard drive? Or any other way that does not require multiple SD Cards. And if it is, I would appreciate a "tutorial" of how to do it.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi can apparently be configured to boot from the network: https://linuxhit.com/raspberry-pi-pxe-boot-netbooting-a-pi-4-without-an-sd-card/ then you don't need an SD card in each Pi.

Comment: It is far from clear what you are proposing. I suggest you drop the term "cluster" as you obviously are not trying to build a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Yes, you can, but there are many steps to doing so (which aren't insurmountable). However, if you are planning to use the cluster for use with docker, then you will also need to set up a iSCSI server as docker images doesn't work with NFS

---

#### Summary

I have done this for a cluster of 5 nodes (including the master) consisting of one Pi 4 8 GB and four Pi 400. I used an SSD on the master as an SD card may not be reliable enough, in the long term.

The various steps that are required are listed below.

Once you get:

- The master node set up (for DHCP, NFS, TFTP), and;
- The first compute node image configured *and booted*

Then adding the rest of the compute node images is just a matter of simple repetition.

I ended up scripting the whole process for ease of repetition and reliability, see [greenonline](https://github.com/greenonline/)/[pxe_pi](https://github.com/greenonline/pxe_pi)

#### Process

1. Use just one SSD, or microSD card, with RaspberryOS 32 bit installed
2. For each compute node (i.e. Pi 400)

   1. Add stable/latest EEPROM firmware
   2. Set boot order `0xf241`
   3. Get MAC and serial
3. On master node (i.e. Pi 4)

   1. Configure `eth1`
   2. Configure `eth0`
   3. `Install dhcp server on `eth0`

      - `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`
      - <del>Comment out option-43 and option-66</del>
      - Don't forget the MAC of the head node 'cluster' and the router
   4. Configure `/etc/hosts`
   5. Optional: managed switch
   6. Optional: additional disk
   7. NFS server
   8. NFS share
   9. TFTP server
   10. Get image (raspbian_lite)
   11. Configure image -

       - Note: the method (using loop devices) is also described here, [Re: Boot multiple PIs from one SSD](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=286091#p1731313)
   12. Set fstab
   13. Set exports
   14. DHCP config
   15. Host file config
   16. Reboot
4. On compute node

   1. Boot (to blue screen)
   2. Log in via SSH
   3. Disable resize
   4. Mount scratch
   5. Set hostname using `raspi-config`
   6. Host file config

      - Set to be the same as that on the master, except that 127.0.1.1 should be the node's hostname (i.e. `rpi1`) and not that of the master node (i.e. `cluster`).
   7. Optional: Secure shell config (rather than doing it in step 5 below)
   8. Reboot
5. Secure shell
6. Port forwarding
7. Adding additional nodes - on the master

   1. Duplicate netboot tftboot and image directories with appropriate named serial and hostname respectively
   2. Modify `/etc/fstab`
   3. Modify `/etc/exports`
   4. Modify `cmdline.txt`
   5. Modify `/etc/hostname`
   6. Modify `/etc/hosts`
   7. Update `/etc/dhcp.conf`
   8. Reboot master
   9. Boot new compute node

#### References

- [Setting up PXE cluster on RPi 4/400](https://wp.me/p6aiNF-8h7)

Also useful (although I didn't follow this guide):

- [Raspberry Pi PXE Boot – Network booting a Pi 4 without an SD card](https://linuxhit.com/raspberry-pi-pxe-boot-netbooting-a-pi-4-without-an-sd-card/)

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. However, you have 1 SD card which can only be inserted into 1 slot at time.

1. All the Pi4's must be able to PXE boot

   a.  You may have to update the firmware

   b.  You may have to set PXE boot mode

This will probably involve plugging the SD card into each of the 64 pi's manually at least once.

```
rpi-eeprom-update -a
```

I am not sure if PXE has to be manually activated or not.

2. Setup SAMBA file sharing
   Configure the PXE server to auto mount the file share you setup.
   You just need to modify the smb.conf file and set the service to auto start on the server.  The files for PXE boot on the server will have to modify /etc/fstab for auto mount.
3. The pxe server will also be the samba server with the 10tb drive attached via USB adapter.